# Не все данные POST попадают в скрипт

Tags: php, http, apache2

Есть вполне рядовая, без ajax/pjax, крупная HTML-форма, отправляет группу полей. Заказчик пожаловался, что не все данные из нее отправляются. Проверил, браузер в панели соединений показывает, что данные отправлены все и корректно.
Но до скрипта-экшна некоторые данные не доходят: если выполнить `print_r($_POST); exit;` в самом начале, это видно.

Пример пропадающих полей:

```
ordering_available_906=on
price_906=1111
left_906=987
xml_export_1[906]=1
xml_export_2[906]=1
xml_export_3[906]=1
sort_order_906=435
```

Пример непропадающих полей:

```
ordering_available_949=on
price_949=683
left_949=987
xml_export_1[949]=1
xml_export_2[949]=1
xml_export_3[949]=1
sort_order_949=750
```

Место, в котором проверяю, точно самое начало вызова - `debug_backtrace()` пуст. htaccess не затрагивает POST. Баг воспроизводится на апачках с РНР 5, как под windows, так и под linux. На другом окружении не пробовал пока. АдБлок отключен. Метод - POST, ответ - 200 OK. В РНР `post_max_size = 0`.

Как такое может быть, что данные пропадают между клиентом и сервером, и постоянно одни и те же?

Немного кода. Пример группы полей, которые не отправляются:

```
<tr style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" class="gridline1">

  <td>
    <input name="selected_product_906" class="checkbox select_product" rel="group-box" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <!-- <td><a href="/published/SC/html/scripts/index.php?ukey=product_settings&amp;productID=906&amp;categoryID=624&amp;sort=name&amp;sort_dir=ASC">se6014&nbsp;</a></td> -->

  <td style="text-align:center; border-left: solid 1px #F5F0BB; border-right: dashed 1px #F5F0BB;
    background-image:url(/my_img/admin_yes_tov-in-site.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;
    ">
    <input name="enabled_906" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center; border-right: solid 1px #F5F0BB; 
    background-image:url(/my_img/admin_yes_sh-card.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;
    ">
    <input name="ordering_available_906" checked="" type="checkbox">
  </td>

  <td style="height:60px!important; font-size:12px;" valign="middle" width="50%">
    <a href="/published/SC/html/scripts/index.php?ukey=product_settings&amp;productID=906&amp;categoryID=624&amp;sort=name&amp;sort_dir=ASC">
      <img src="/published/publicdata/B02/attachments/SC/products_pictures/moya-kosmetichka-rf-seaofspa-luxury-body-cream_1_1_1_thm.jpg" style="margin-right:10px; float:left;" height="50" width="50"><span style="font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold;">Артикул : se6014</span>
      <br>Увлажняющий крем для тела с минералами мертвого моря 200мл, Black Pearl Sea of spa (Си оф спа)</a>
  </td>
  <!-- <td align="right"><a href="/published/SC/html/scripts/index.php?ukey=product_settings&amp;productID=906&amp;categoryID=624&amp;sort=name&amp;sort_dir=ASC">
    0&nbsp;
    </a></td> -->
  <td style="border-left: solid 1px #F5F0BB;border-right: solid 1px #F5F0BB; 
                                    " align="center">
    <input class="multiply_price" name="price_906" size="8" value="1111" style="margin:0 5px 10px 5px;" type="text">
  </td>
  <td style="border-right: solid 1px #F5F0BB;
            " align="center" valign="middle">
    <input name="left_906" size="5" value="987" type="text">
  </td>
  <!-- <td align="right">0</td> -->
  <!--  -->
  <td align="center">
    <input name="xml_export_1[906]" checked="" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input name="xml_export_2[906]" checked="" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td style="background-image:url(/my_img/admin_yes_price.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; padding-left:30px!important; padding-right:30px!important;" align="center">
    <input name="xml_export_3[906]" checked="" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td align="center">
    <input name="xml_export_4[906]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </td>
  <td style="border-left: solid 1px #F5F0BB; font-size:11px;" align="center" valign="middle">
  </td>
  <td style="border-left: solid 1px #F5F0BB; border-right: solid 1px #F5F0BB;" align="center">
    <input name="sort_order_906" value="435" size="5" type="text">
  </td>
  <!-- <td style="border-left: dashed 1px #F5F0BB;"><a href='/published/SC/html/scripts/index.php?ukey=categorygoods&amp;categoryID=624&amp;sort=name&amp;sort_dir=ASC&amp;did=14&amp;action=delete_product&amp;productID=906' title='Удалить?' class="confirm_action"><img src="images_common/remove.gif" border="0" alt='Удалить' /></a></td> -->
  <td style="border-right: solid 1px #F5F0BB;" align="center" valign="middle">
    <a target="_blank" href="/product/906/">
      <img src="/my_img/tov_go_to_site.png" alt="" height="30" border="0" width="27">
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: может всё-таки добавить в вопрос немного кода? а ещё попробуйте данные поменять местами при отправке, пропадут те же поля или какие-то другие, это может приблизить к пониманию проблемы.

Comment: если поменять данные местами, то эти поля не пропадают. код сейчас добавлю в сообщение

Comment: Если поискать по коду поиском, названия пропадающих полей - они в одном экземпляре? Не могут они перекрываться дублирующими полями ввода с такими же названиями, расположенными ниже в форме?

Comment: Нет, не перекрываются. Да и в этом случае из них приходило бы хоть что-нибудь, а так - их вообще нет в $_POST

Comment: А куда при отправке пропадают другие чекбоксы: selected_product_906, enabled_906 и `xml_export_4[906]`, может дело в них? И кода мало, если у вас инфа пропадает при попадании в бэкенд, то и бэкенд нужен, а также код непропадающего блока инфы и в сравнении искать 10 отличий

Comment: Много мух и котлет в вопросе. Надо разделять: с какой стороны данные пропадают? Их клиент отправляет (инструменты разработчика в браузере или полновесный сетевой сниффер)? Проблема воспроизводится при формировании такого же запроса курлом (да хоть неткатом/телнетом, благо HTTP/1.x такое ещё позволяет)? Что в свою очередь PHP видит в теле запроса `file_get_contents('php://input')`? Сколько всего аргументов передаётся? Попробуйте уменьшить их число (лимит max_input_vars или веб-сервера - разберёмся позже, сперва найти граничный случай).

Comment: Написал все что удалось установить. В том числе то, что состав отправляемых данных просматривается в панели соеинений браузера (да, в инструментах разработчика).

Comment: Знаете, кажется, max_input_vars помогло, пока, по крайней мере на локалхосте. Только я так и не нашел, какое же значение работает по умолчанию, у меня директива была закомментирована.

Comment: 1000 по-умолчанию, http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php Можно в phpinfo() уточнить, какие значения параметров используются. Напомню, что у веб-сервера могут быть свои лимиты дополнительно.